# how to make chess board pattern in c?

Tags: c

I am breaking my head to achieve something. 
just trying using printf("****\n*****\n*****\n"); and doesn't work.

Could anyone help me with this?

Apologies guys my question was badly written.
[example for 1 input : 5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpRET.png)
the algorithm is similar to summing up all numbers of a int matrix.

question:

> ```
>      *****
>      *****
>      *****
> *****
> *****
> *****
> if input : 2
>      *****
>      *****
>      *****
> *****     *****
> *****     *****
> *****     *****
>      *****
>      *****
>      *****
> if input : 3
> ```

main code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int rows, cols, i, j, k;

    /* Input rows and columns from user */
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    k = 1;

    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {
        for(j=1; j<=cols; j++)
        {
            if(k == 1)
            {
                printf("111\n111\n111");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("0");
            }

            // If k = 1  then k *= -1 => -1
            // If k = -1 then k *= -1 =>  1
            k *= -1;
        }

        if(cols % 2 == 0)
        {
            k *= -1;
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: your code prints `0` and `1`, but no `*`. please clearly describe how you test your program and what is the difference between observed and expected output.

Comment: Could you convince us that the shown code is by you (some indicators exist that it is not at all understood by you)? Could you explain for each code line what you believe it does? That will help to put you on the right thinking track. Also please state whether the proposed compromise here is applicable: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    int rows, cols, i, j, k,l;

    /* Input rows and columns from user */
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    printf("Enter number of columns: ");
    scanf("%d", &cols);

    k = 1;

    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {

      for(l=1; l<=3; l++)
    {


      for(j=1; j<=cols; j++)
    {
       if(k==1){
      if(j%2==1){
           printf("***");
      }
      else{
          printf("   ");

      }
       }
       else{
      if(j%2==1){
           printf("   ");
      }
      else{

           printf("***");
      }
       }


    }


      printf("\n");
      if(l==3)
     k=(-1)*k;
    }





    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Would you like to improve your code-only answer by adding some explanation? Demonstrating some consistent coding style would also make it more appealing.

Comment: Be careful if you see signs that OP is not understanding the shown code at all. Are you aware of the discussion in the link I provided? You are entitled to your own opinion, but please read it.

Answer (score 0):

First you are writing `1` and `0` not `*****` and `"     "`.
So those should be changed.

Then as soon as you do `\n` it gets really tricky to write something in this line later on. So you should generate your field line by line not block by block.

With this in mind. It should be possible for you to figure it out.

Some pseudo code to guide you (not tested but the general direction should be okay):

```
for i < rows:
  for k < rows:
    for j < cols:
      if (i + j) % 2 
        print("*****")
      else
        print("     ")
    print("\n")
```

Comment: Be careful if you see signs that OP is not understanding the shown code at all. Are you aware of the discussion in the link I provided? You are entitled to your own opinion, but please read it.

Comment: @Yunnosch Will have a look at it. But as the problem with the code was quite general, the answer was general with some pseudo code to encourage to think about it more.

Comment: That is pretty much the proposed compromise and I approve of it. I made however good experience with referring to that description, in order to make OP also aware and to rope them into some own effort on finding out themselves and also on improving the question. My respect for being open towards a slightly nagging comment like mine.